# UserDefaults data is deleting after close the app in iPAD

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3

Hi i am developing an Universal app,In my app after user login i am storing token Id in locally by using uderdefaults.When ever i close the app that time user defaults is clearing automatically.In iPhone data is not clearing automatically but in iPad only data is clearing.I need this info,when user logout that time only i need to clear these data.following code i used for storing data.

```
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(signUpInfo.devicetoken.token, forKey: "auth_token")
        defaults.set(signUpInfo.devicetoken.name, forKey: "user_Name")
        defaults.set(signUpInfo.devicetoken.mobile, forKey: "mobileNumber")
        defaults.set(signUpInfo.devicetoken.email, forKey: "email")
        defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Code here looks like it should work fine. Are you sure this code is being hit on iPad and that `devicetoken` contains information?

Comment: Please confirm by printing value of specified key. check with Key, some times spelling mistake take place.... Code is correct.

Comment: Data is stored .If i close the app these data is deleting automatically.I am not deleting these data.This is happens only in iPad

Comment: There is no need to call `synchronize`. Also, if the token is sensitive you should store it in the keychain rather than user defaults.

Comment: that is fine but if i remove "synchronize" also there is no change right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Setting is like

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "key")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And working perfectly fine. But instead of setObject use setValue. Will be proven good in future(this is what i have heard from my sr. but not sure about this).
like

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("Value", forKey: "token")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: In swift3 there is no UserDefaults.standard.setObject("Value", forKey: "token")
this syntax.

Comment: I have updated answer with setValue. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: for me data storing perfectly but that data is deleting automatically when i close the app in iPad.

Comment: Your code seems proper, Can you verify that are you removing values from user default anytime? May be one of such method is getting called due to which you may lost your user default datas

Comment: No ,but how it is working in iPhone.That is strange for me.

Comment: Ha ha ha, This typical developers issue... I have faced such things many time due to some silly mistake.

Comment: Please update me for same once you figure out the exact cause of the issue in ipad

Comment: There's no need to call `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` anymore (since iOS8). Run tests with/without in your apps, you will see for yourself.